# Access log "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 400

Tags: login, errors, security

I'm looking the access log and I tried some lines as:

> IP - - [date and hour] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 400 ...

What's the problem? Someone wants hack my blog? How can I resolve?

Comment: Why are you worried about hits to your login page? There is at least one user on the site, you, that would need to login once in awhile. Are you seeing a lot of these?

Comment: @s_ha_dum about 15 in 2 days. But some hours doesn't coincide with my access. I haven't other users...

Answer (score 1):

15 in two days is nothing. I've seen thousands per day. If your passwords are good, don't worry about it but please make sure the passwords are good by nerd standards and not by common standards.

If it really worries you, there are plugins out there like Limit Login Attempts that can help and I believe that the site's highest ranked user, toscho, was working on a similar plugin but I don't know the status of that.

Comment: Now, I installed the plugin "Wordfence Security" and the results are 4 login attempts with the username "admin" (not existing). Don't I have to worry?